# Create multiple empty directories fast on FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have almost 200 text files in my laptop, I wrote the code in C# which reads these text files line by line and makes a directory per each line in FTP server.

This is my code:

```
static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\file_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') + ".txt");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/dir/" + line);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

But this is very slow to create directories, are there other faster ways to do this? For example, get text file as an array and than create all of its directories.

Comment: The slow part of your program is certainly not your textfile reading.

Answer (score 1):

Reading of the text file is really not the problem. The slow part is the FTP.

Use more threads to [parallelize the processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming):

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
        {
            var lines =
                File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\file_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') + ".txt");

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/dir/" + line);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                request.GetResponse();
            }
        }
    ));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Though note that you should also take care of disposing the `WebResponse`'s.

Answer (score 0):

The slow part of your programm are the requests you are sending one by one.
You can do some tricks to speed them up:

```
// allow more connections at a time
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 30;
// don't wait the 100ms every request do
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Further you can send the request in multi-threading, so you don't have to wait for every request until it's finished. But be aware, that a lot of request can bring down a server. 200 shouldn't be a problem.

Here you have some code you could test:

```
static void Main()
{
    // allow more connections at a time
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 30;
    // don't wait the 100ms every request do
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\file_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') + ".txt");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp/dir/" + line);
                        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                        request.GetResponse();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }
                }
            ));
        }
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```